# Interromper loop foreach do PHP depois de iniciado

Tags: php, mysql, servidor, foreach

Como interromper um `foreach` do PHP com base em uma condição vinda do banco depois de iniciado o loop?

```
        $smtm = Connect::getInstance()->query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE num IS NULL");
        foreach ($smtm->fetchAll() as $value) {
            //aqui vai o comando a ser executado.
            if (Connect::getInstance()->query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE num IS NULL")) {
                //encerra o loop se não encontrar NULL
                break;
            }
        }
```

Como o BD pode ser alterado em tempo de execução, gostaria de efetuar o `break` caso a consulta do banco atenda a condição durante o loop.

Comment: Continua fora do escopo sua pergunta! Break é o suficiente para parar um laço de repetição, o problema está em sua condição para tal, sugiro rever seu código para que você mesmo consiga entender o que quer.